# Netbeans, C++ and Git

Tags: c++, git, netbeans

so I'm using NB with the C++ plugin and Git version control so I can work with colleagues.

I don't know what files are supposed to be "tracked" and we are getting problems because if we only add the code files to git, new files are not being automatically add to NB but only in the physical folder. We figured out that the configuration file is the problem but if we had it to repository we get another problem, absolute paths to the files.

What is the solution for this?

Cheers

Comment: What paths are being stored as absolute paths? Libraries, sources, resources?

Comment: Sources and headers files..

Comment: I would expect that NB keeps the relative files, at least if they are below the project directory, isn't it?

Comment: The project files are inside the project in NB. I just want to know if you should "commit" project configuration files and use relative paths in the C++ NB options.

Comment: Ah, then, the answer is obviously "yes", you should. Without these configuration files the project will not work properly.

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks a lot! (;
BTW, what we should have in gitignore file? I already found some examples but none were to c++ with NB

Comment: I don't know NB very well but everything that is generated should be in gitignore, so that the output of `git status` is clean. That is, every file in a normal build dir. is either added or ignored.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't know what files are supposed to be "tracked"

As a rule of thumb:

- Source / test files
- NetBeans project files `nbproject` (some files only, *see below!*)
- Possible project related files, that are not generated for each compilation
- Makefile

What shouldn't go into git (and therefore onto your gitignore):

- `build` directory
- `dist` directory
- within `nbproject` ignore these:

  - `private` dir
  - The `Package-*` and `Makefile-*` files

About the last (Package-* / Makefile-*) files i'm not completely sure - please try with them on gitignore first.

---

Let's assume such a project - put everything with a (x) on gitignore:

```
<project>
|
+- build/ (x)
|
+- dist/ (x)
|
+- nbproject/
|   |
|   +- private (x)
|   |
|   +- some files (as above)
|
+- src/
|
+- test/
|
+- Makefile
```